# Windows Defender vs. Security Essentials in Windows 8

Tags: security, windows-8, ms-security-essentials, windows-defender

What is the difference between Windows Defender on Windows 8 and Microsoft Security Essentials? They practically look alike, so is there a need to install Security Essentials?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the Windows Defender of Windows 8 differs heavily from the one in Windows 7 and this is a Windows 8 related question.

Comment: You are exactly right. This closed-as-duplicate reason is fallacious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft says](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security-essentials-download)

> Windows Defender for Windows 8 and Windows RT provides the same level
>   of protection against malware as Microsoft Security Essentials. You
>   can't use Microsoft Security Essentials with Windows 8, but you don't
>   need to — Windows Defender is already included and ready to go. But if
>   you’re looking to protect a PC with an older version of Windows, you
>   can use Microsoft Security Essentials to help guard against viruses,
>   spyware, and other malicious software. It provides free real-time
>   protection for your home or small business PCs.

When you try to install the MS Essentials on your Windows 8 then you will get a popup message from `Program  Compatibility Assistant`

> This program has a compatibility issues

[image]

As we can see Windows 8 come along with Windows Defender which has the same feature as MS Essentials has on older Windows.

You have to update it like MS Essential to keep your system protected.

[image]

You have the setting options like MS Essential.

[image]

I'm just looking a new feature Microsoft Active Protection Service(MAPS) in the settings tab or may be its already there and I noticed it now.

[image]

Only they are giving a lack of integration of right click and scan a file/folder/drive which you can achieve with a registry hack. For this read my [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/494018/how-to-add-the-windows-defender-into-windows-explorers-right-click-menu-to-scan).

Comment: MAPS is the new name for Microsoft SpyNet, which I'm pretty sure used to be in MSSE...but then I've been using ForeFront Client Security/System Center Endpoint Protection for some time now and they both definitely have it

Comment: @Kirk check out my answer to clear it. :)

Comment: @Kirk you will get that warning(as shown in image) in Windows 8 when you will try it to install.

Answer (score 9):

Security Essentials was integrated into the system on Windows 8 and does not need to be installed.

Comment: That means Security Essentials is obsolete and will only be useful to Windows 7 (and below) users, right?

Comment: The standalone setup is, yes.

Comment: @MichaelK do you have a source for this? Just curious on reading up on it

Comment: @Kirk take a Windows 8 and try to install Security Essentials with the setup from their website. Then it will tell you.