# How do I virus scan an individual file under Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, windows-defender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add the Windows defender into Windows Explorer’s right click menu to scan a particular drive/folder/file on demand?](https://superuser.com/questions/494018/how-to-add-the-windows-defender-into-windows-explorers-right-click-menu-to-scan)

From what I understand, Windows 8's version of Defender has all the functionality of Microsoft Security Essentials and MSE is no longer needed under 8.

This is all well and good, but one of the features I used very often under my Windows 7 install of MSE was virus scanning an individual file by using the right click context menu.

I see no such option under 8, is there a way to enable it or otherwise get this functionality back?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/494018/how-to-add-the-windows-defender-into-windows-explorers-right-click-menu-to-scan see my answer there.

Comment: Ah thanks for the link, I will mark to close this question as the duplicate. Just FYI, you can link directly to an answer by using the share link under the answer itself.

Comment: I know that but my slow bandwidth didn't let me do it. :D